# Share instance with multiples connections in PHP

Tags: php, memcached

Can i create a global object shared between multiple connections?

For example, I have a table that I want to store in memory using memcache, but I do not want every user to one instance in memory is created, I would like to share for each connection this instance, like a pointer to memory.

Can I do it?

If i can, is this a good method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found some tools that can be used for these features !

In pure **PHP**
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.apc.php

**Varnish** (server api)

[https://www.varnish-cache.org/project](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.apc.php)